# Make form always stick to desktop like Win 7 gadget (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Ok, I'm aware there's a lots of topis about this, but I haven't found anything that works for me.

My program generates a small picture that i would like to keep in a WinForm that's always at the bottom, "with the desktop". Something like the gadgets in windows 7.

How do i tell my form to always stay here, and just can't be visible over any other form/window?

Should'nt this be doable like in the form_load function for this window?

Like this

```
Private Sub Sticky_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeepMeAtTheBottomUntillIAmClosed
End Sub
```

Comment: why not just make it a Gadget if that is the behavior you seek?

Comment: Yea, that's a thougt and that was the plan from the start. The problem, how ever, is that the users will be in the range of OS:es all from XP to 8. Otherwise i guess that would be the ultimate solution, yes.

Comment: My impression is, that this cannot be done. There are boatloads of programs (think browser bar ) which would love such a feature and yet I see no such program in the wild. I think Microsoft has forbidden this behaviour because programs would use this feature to block acess to the desktop.
ALso: gadgets are no longer an option, they are deprecated even on Win 7 since a few months.

Comment: Well, that was a good comment i must say. I guess another option then is to have a notifyicon or something, and when the user press this, it will appear in a small box by the task bar. This, how ever, will probably make the user forget about it. And, for that matters, the user would probably forget about it if it stays at the desk as well since i know no user that stares at the desktop all day. The image displays a picture of a generated chart, and it has really no rules for when it's about time to alert the user about something important. I guess i'll have to rethink this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create a form that has no border and no controlbox, the user will not be able to resize or move it. Then add your own button to allow it to close, tell it where you want it to be and tada!

You can even add some mouse over functionality to make the tools appear when you are over the form.

Comment: Hmm. Interesting indeed! But, I don't mind if the user moves it or anything like that, i think i would actually prefer this. But, would it be visible only at desktop level, or could it be displayed over other windows?

Comment: Hah! That's quite awesome i must say. Simple and it works! Onw problem is tho, that if it is displayed over some icons, I can't reach the icons since i can't move the form. Maybe i should add like four small "Arrow-buttons" that moves the window some pixels in the specified direction. :)  Really cool function. My plan was to leave this function out, but now i really have to have this as an option! Thx! :-)

Comment: BTW... do you have any ideas how to remove the icon in the activity field for this form...? :)

Comment: I dont know what you mean by "icon in the activity field".  Are you taking about the taskbar? If so, there is a property for the form called "ShowInTaskBar".

Comment: Yea, sorry. That's what i ment. I'm not really used to windows and I always forget the terms, so i tried the direct swedish translation which i remembered - but you got it right, and that was the thing i was looking for.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. Sure, it may prevent it from popping up in front of other windows, but it doesn't make it stick to the desktop. 

I feel in the past i've been able to do this... A combination of send to bottom and detecting certain keypresses to detect if the desktop is being shown via a key combination (Windows + D).