# Lock Windows Form Location in VB

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, position, location

I have a program that requires the form to be shown in the bottom right corner of the screen. I've done some research and it says that setting me.location= will lock the forms location but it doesn't seem to be working. The code is below:

---

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Position form to lower right hand corner of screen

    Me.Visible = True
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width
    y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height

    Do Until x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
        x = x - 1
        Me.Location = New Point(x, y)
    Loop

End Sub
```

---

I need the form to have Minimize, Close buttons and be locked to the bottom right corner when it is not Minimized or Closed.

I'm Using VB 2010 Express

Cheers.

Comment: UPDATE:
since I've added this same code to the second form in the program the second Form just freezes. Something is definitely up with this code. I am wondering why Form 1 it works to position the form (but users can freely move it after) and Form 2 causes the program to freeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

> Update:

A better solution would be:

```
Public Class Form1

' Just to set and store custom locations
Dim Corners As New Dictionary(Of String, Point) 

' Flag to make/unmake form moveable
Private bMoveable As Boolean = True

Private Declare Function EnableMenuItem Lib "user32.dll" Alias "EnableMenuItem" (ByVal hMenu As IntPtr, ByVal uIDEnableItem As Int32, ByVal uEnable As Int32) As Int32

Public Overridable Property Moveable() As Boolean
    Get
        Return bMoveable
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As Boolean)
        If bMoveable <> Value Then
            bMoveable = Value
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As Message)

    If m.Msg = &H117& Then
        'Handles popup of system menu.
        If m.LParam.ToInt32 \ 65536 <> 0 Then 'divide by 65536 to get hiword.
            Dim AbleFlags As Int32 = &H0&
            If Not Moveable Then AbleFlags = &H2& Or &H1&
            EnableMenuItem(m.WParam, &HF010&, &H0& Or AbleFlags)
        End If
    End If

    If Not Moveable Then
        'Cancels any attempt to drag the window by it's caption.
        If m.Msg = &HA1 Then If m.WParam.ToInt32 = &H2 Then Return
        'Redundant but cancels any clicks on the Move system menu item.
        If m.Msg = &H112 Then If (m.WParam.ToInt32 And &HFFF0) = &HF010& Then Return
    End If

    'Return control to base message handler.
    MyBase.WndProc(m)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown

    ' Add a custom location to the dictionary
    Corners.Add("BottomRight", _
      New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width, _
                Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height))

    ' Move the form
    Me.Location = Corners("BottomRight")

    ' Make it unmoveable from there!
    Me.Moveable = False

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Verifying this now. Thanks for your response!

Comment: THIS IS PERFECT! THANKS YOU HAVE MY UPVOTE. Whoever Downovoted must have not seen the Update!

Comment: @DaveyLions Thankyou so much, and feel free to ask if something of the code it's unclear to you.

Answer (score 2):

Why dont you check on this post ([Make form always stick to desktop like Win 7 gadget (VB.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383495/make-form-always-stick-to-desktop-like-win-7-gadget-vb-net/19384604#19384604)) where I answered a very similar question.

Comment: This works as a work around. Good idea! Just wish I knew the proper way to code it

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Move(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Move
    Me.Location = New Point(30, 30)
End Sub
```

Comment: Mike, thanks for this, I just have to ask, I'm going to try this now, what is the significance of (30,30)? Don't we need to calculate where the corner is based on carrying screen resolutions?

Comment: Did not work. It locks the form at 30,30 instead of right corner

Answer (score 0):

Try this out...

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1

    Private LockPt As Point
    Private Const WM_MOVING As Integer = &H216

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.MaximizeBox = False
        Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle

        LockPt.X = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
        LockPt.Y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - Me.Height
        Me.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, LockPt.Y)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        While Me.Location.X > Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - Me.Width
            Me.Location = New Point(Me.Location.X - 1, LockPt.Y)
        End While
    End Sub

    Private Structure RECT
        Public Left As Integer
        Public Top As Integer
        Public Right As Integer
        Public Bottom As Integer
    End Structure

    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case WM_MOVING
                Dim rc As RECT = Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, GetType(RECT))
                rc.Left = LockPt.X
                rc.Top = LockPt.Y
                rc.Right = rc.Left + Me.Width
                rc.Bottom = rc.Top + Me.Height
                Marshal.StructureToPtr(rc, m.LParam, True)
        End Select

        MyBase.WndProc(m)
    End Sub

End Class
```